# Find regular expression or list of regular expressions across multiple text files and extract matching lines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.7, text-mining

## The issue

Caveat: I am good at regular expressions, but I am a Python novice. I have tried to read as extensively as possible and could not find a solution that matched my scenario, so I am asking this question.

I wish to accomplish the following:

1. Loop through all the text files in a folder (I might use .docx / xml files at some point, but I will figure out the details). I suspect this is a matter of iterating, but I do not understand how to do it here;
2. Search for regular expressions OR a list of regular expressions contained in a file (as with a gazetteer), ideally stored in an external .txt or .csv file;
3. Print (or, better yet, write to CSV or Pandas) the name of the file, the match as found, and the line of text containing the latter. Ideally, these would go in different columns of a spreadsheet, so they could be comma separated values, but a dictionary would work just as well.

I had some success with code of this kind, which has allowed me to successfully print matching lines. With about six hours of Python experience in total, I felt pretty happy.

```
import re

def main():
        regex = re.compile("regex")
        with open("text_file.txt") as f:
            for line in f:
                result = regex.findall(line)
                if result == None:
                    continue
                elif result == []:
                    continue
                else:
                    print(f, result, line)

main()
```

## Problems and goals:

- It returns all capture groups for the regular expression (I have multiple capture groups) before the matching line. This is not a problem, but I would like to be able to manipulate this in some way in the future;
- I would like to be able to reuse the objects (filename, match, line) for further manipulation and analysis, ideally importing it all into pandas object, but I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestion would be massively appreciated;
- When a regex matches multiple patterns in the same line, it only returns one line containing the matches. However, I would like for one such instance to be handled differently. Specifically, I would like for it to return as many lines as there are matches. Consider the example string:

> ```
> We used to call Bob "Little Bobby"
> ```

My regular expression "Bob(by)?" will match "Bob" and "Bobby". But my code will print something like this (if I am not mistaken).

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='text_file.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> [('Bob', ''), ('Bobby', ('by')) We used to call Bob "Little Bobby"
```

Instead, I want it to print two lines (one for the "Bob" match and one for the "Bobby" match. This can be done relatively easily in grep, if I recall correctly, but I can't find anything helpful in the re module documentation.

Comment: You probably want to look at [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and/or [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Loop through all the text files in a folder (I might use .docx / xml files at some point, but I will figure out the details). I suspect this is a matter of iterating, but I do not understand how to do it here;

Yes, you need to iterate. I recommend using [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) depending on your needs.

Example:

```py
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('/path/to/my/dir', '*.txt'):
    print(filename)
    # do other stuff with filename
```

> 2. Search for regular expressions OR a list of regular expressions contained in a file (as with a gazetteer), ideally stored in an external .txt or .csv file;

I recommend using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) or [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer).

Example:

```py
import re

my_re = re.compile('whatever your regex is')
with open(filename) as f:
    file_contents = f.read()
    for match in my_re.findall(file_contents):
        print(match)
        # do whatever you want with the match here
```

To extract groups from a match, you need to use the [`.groups`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups) function.

> 3. Print (or, better yet, write to CSV or Pandas) the name of the file, the match as found, and the line of text containing the latter. Ideally, these would go in different columns of a spreadsheet, so they could be comma separated values, but a dictionary would work just as well.

You can load all of the data into a Python `list` of `dict`s and then use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library for outputting it to a CSV.

Example:

```py
import csv

list_of_data = [{ ... }, { ... }]

with open(output_filename, 'w+') as f:
    # this specifies what the headers of your CSV will be.
    # you can also just specify a list of strings here
    fieldnames = list_of_data[0].keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for item in list_of_data:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks great. I think I understand the general direction I have to follow now!